# Non-www to www redirection is not working for some cases?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, asp-classic, web-config

Redirect rule in `.htaccess` file in public_html folder for **non-www to www**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:/www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Non-WWW Not Working URL:**

```
http://domain.com/http:/www.domain.com/images/bike.jpg
```

I added customErrors in the config file. The above URL should go to custom 404 page. But this is not happened and shows Server Error in '/' Application.

[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqoI9.png)

But below non-www URL works fine.

**Non-WWW Working URL:**

```
http://domain.com/http/www.domain.com/images/bike.jpg
```

If I add WWW, it works fine.

How can I solve this?

**WWW Working URL:** `http://www.domain.com/http:/www.domain.com/images/bike.jpg`

Comment: Add redirection rule in web.config, will always redirect with wwww

Comment: @Div I have added redirect for custom errors like this <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" >
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="404.html" />
  </customErrors>
    </system.web>

Comment: Your question is not cleared to me, Both are given 404, what should you expect?

Comment: Both URLs in comment seems like same, isn't it?

Comment: sry please check now the comment

Comment: @Div I'm redirecting 400 errors to custom 404 page but for this domain.com/http:/www.domain.com/images/bike.jpg it is not happening but works fine in this case [http://www.domain.com/http:/www.domain.com/images/bike.jpg](http://www.domain.com/http:/www.domain.com/images/bike.jpg) i.e if it has www in the url so the issue is in non-www redirect to www that only I can't able to figure it out

Comment: *errors to custom 404 page but for this domain.com/http:/www.domain.com/images/bike.jpg it is not happening* then what you get on this?

Comment: gets the following error

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Comment: Are you sure, I pasted in my browser and it's give 404.